# Safety of Covid-19 vaccine for pregnant women

Tags: coronavirus, safety, vaccine

Is there any possibility that the protein produced by COVID-19 mRNA vaccine taken into body could cause negative effect for unborn babies?

In particular, isn't it possible the protein could be used as part of the baby of the pregnant woman?

In addition, mRNA can be broken by thermal fluctuation, so I worry that this broken mRNA might produce unexpectedly harmful protein for the body. Is this risk possibly realized?

Comment: Why do you think the protein would 'be used to become part of the pregnant woman' or 'produce unexpectedly harmful protein for the body'?

Comment: In a very recent case, an unvaccinated mother gave birth to her baby, held her *once*, and she died 10 days later of Covid-19. How, when the vaccine is so new, can we determine all of its effects on intrauterine offspring? However, the lack of a mother has definite known negative side effects.

Answer (score 7):

The CDC has evaluated COVID-19 vaccines for pregnant people, and [has determined that they are safe](https://www.cdc.gov/media/releases/2021/s0811-vaccine-safe-pregnant.html).

The main worry that they were addressing, however, was not either of your concerns (which do not make sense biologically). Instead, they were looking at whether the reaction of the body to the vaccine would be a potential cause of miscarriage.  The answer is: no, it's not.

Instead, we should be encouraging pregnant people to get vaccinated so that they will be less likely to die or become seriously ill, which will definitely have a bad effect on their unborn baby.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. ok, I am totally new to biology and my concern might be off the point, but I am sincerely trying to understand why scientifically this mRNA vaccine is believed to be safe. Could you kindly answer SPECIFICALLY what does not make sense biologically?
1. How can you prove that the protein made by the mRNA does not affect unborn baby?
2. How can you rule out the possibility that the proteins made by broken mRNA is not toxic to human?

Comment: I would suggest studying some of the basics on how cells, proteins, and pregnancies work. mRNA is being degraded continually unless it's stabilized, so when mRNA gets broken, it gets rapidly recycled and you get no product, not a toxic product. As for impact on unborn babies, big proteins won't pass the placental barrier at all, so they simply cannot get to the baby in the first place.

Comment: As for "how do we prove ... ?", "how do we rule out ...?"  The only way to **prove** that the vaccines are safe for pregnant women, or more precisely to evaluate their risk (since nothing is 100% safe), is to run a randomized clinical trial. This is (1) slow, (2) expensive, (3) unethical because we **don't** have any reason to believe that they're unsafe (so it wouldn't be fair to the pregnant women we left in the control group who got COVID). "Prove it" is a bit like "prove I won't be eaten by a crocodile on my front porch" (even if I live in New Jersey).

Comment: @jakebeal, you could add the second and third sentence of your comment to your answer ...

Comment: Some immunoglobulins (IgG) are known to cross the placenta. They usually *help* the infant, not harm them, making a potential case for the safety of the vaccine. (Also, sorry that I repeated one of your points to the OP. I had not read your answer at that point.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse True, though the transfer of IgG is mediated by a specific targeted mechanism, so the basic point about proteins not passing through remains, and I hope the (inevitable) exception doesn't confuse the OP.

Comment: Thank you all for kindly answering question from layman. My knowledge on biology is from what I've read the textbook of essential cell biology, so not enough to understand papers on mRNA vaccines, but thanks for explaining in easy words.
@BenBolker I get your point, maybe my words were too strong, the proof of safety is like devil's proof.

Comment: @jakebeal OK, so there is enough reason to believe harmful proteins will not enter placenta generally. I will believe it.

Comment: @jakebeal What about the first question? it will take a while (~hours to days?) for mRNA to be broken by brownian motion, so if the broken mRNA is still able to produce corresponding protein, aren't there any possibilities that one of those proteins might be harmful to human?

Comment: @HQMA Cells regulate mRNA quite aggressively for many reasons, including preventing production of harmful proteins by RNA-based viruses. Those same mechanisms will generally prevent what you are worrying about. See, for example, this survey: https://www.nature.com/articles/nrm2104

Comment: @jakebeal Thank you for your comment, it's good to know there are such arguments to suggest the safety